# Add a single key to to CA certificates from an automated script

Tags: debian, ssl, certificates

I'm doing some automation for a local machine in Vagrant using Puppet.

I need to add a CA certificate to the trusted list in Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 LTS. I simply add the file to the right place:

```
file { 'godaddy-ca-cert':
    path   => '/usr/share/ca-certificates/godaddy-ca.crt',
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    mode   => '0644',
    source => "puppet:///modules/certificates/godaddy-ca.pem"
}
```

What I can do to manually add the certificate? Typically I've  done the following manually to update certificates:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

However, this doesn't work as it requires manual input. How can I automate adding root CA authorities without any manual input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `update-ca-certificates` command. That should not require any user input.

However, you're installing the certificate in the wrong place; you want to put it in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`; that is the directory for locally-added certificates and any added there are automatically trusted.

If you really want to put it in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/`, you'll have to add it to `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` (to make it trusted) before calling `update-ca-certificates`.

Comment: just a little warning, if your root type `update-ca-certificates --refresh` it will remove local added CAs